# Why this error come out? 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

I am new in coding Pinescript... I'm facing with this error message "line 15: Mismatched input 'Ciao' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'."

```
study("Il mio Script")
Lenght=50
SMA50=sma(close, 50)

SMA50DIV=SMA50-close

High50=highest(SMA50DIV,Lenght)

Low50=lowest(SMA50DIV,Lenght)
```

//Error the following row

```
if close<=(SMA50)  Ciao=-(100-(100/(Low50/SMA50DIV))) else Ciao=(100-(100/(High50/SMA50DIV)))
```

//

```
plot(Ciao, color=color.yellow, title="SHIFT50", linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciao Sandrino,

Included below is an example of your original, only formatted to perform without error. I have included some notes for you in the script. Like Gustavo said, a ternary operator is a great solution, but using if or else is acceptable too. Here is how:

```
//@version=4
study("Il mio Script")
Lenght=50
SMA50=sma(close, 50)

SMA50DIV=SMA50-close

High50=highest(SMA50DIV,Lenght)

Low50=lowest(SMA50DIV,Lenght)

    // first declare variable globally. You will get an error if this is not done 

Ciao = 0.0

    // then re-assign variable locally under your conditions 
    // note that 'if' and 'else' must be in separate lines with 'Ciao' having one indentation 

if close<=(SMA50)  
    Ciao := -(100-(100/(Low50/SMA50DIV))) 
else 
    Ciao := (100-(100/(High50/SMA50DIV)))

    // ternary operator is cleaner and easier for some to understand 
//Ciao = close<=(SMA50) ? -(100-(100/(Low50/SMA50DIV))) : (100-(100/(High50/SMA50DIV)))

plot(Ciao, color=color.yellow, title="SHIFT50", linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line)
```

Cheers, and good luck with your trading and coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Ternary conditional operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D)

```
Ciao = close<=(SMA50) ? -(100-(100/(Low50/SMA50DIV))) : (100-(100/(High50/SMA50DIV)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestions. It's works! I do not understand what was wrong in my previous script..